# Most Efficient Way to Define New Column in MySQL using Calculated Columns

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm creating a report with calculated fields that are based off other calculated fields in my data. Currently, I'm creating a table to define the first set of calculated fields and then creating a new table where I select all the fields from the first table then define my 2nd set of calculated fields using the calculated fields from the first table. For example, this is part of the code below:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS table.Paids_2;
CREATE TABLE table.Paids_2 AS 
SELECT ID_Source, TPA_Claim_Number, File, ADJ, Policy_Number, Claimant, 
Insured, Report_Date, Accident_Date, Company, BusinessDivision, Subdivision, 
SectionName, GreatPlainsCode, Premium_State, ASL, Accident_Year, DAC, 
Claims_IND, Hurricane, Hurricane_Catastrophe_Description, CAT,Total_Recovery, 
LOB, Risk_Country, Clmnt, Effective_Date, Effective_Year, Expiration_Date, 
Sub_Policy_Number, Policy_Type, Policy_Symbol, WINS_Claim_Number, 
Claim_Description, Q2_2018_ITD_PaidLoss, Q2_2018_ITD_PaidALAE, 
Q2_2018_ITD_Deductible_PaidLoss, Q2_2018_ITD_Deductible_PaidALAE, 
Q4_2017_ITD_PaidLoss, Q4_2017_ITD_PaidALAE, Q4_2017_ITD_Deductible_PaidLoss, 
Q4_2017_ITD_Deductible_PaidALAE,
CAST(TRIM(Q2_2018_ITD_PaidLoss) - TRIM(Q2_2018_ITD_PaidALAE) AS 
decimal(20,2)) AS Q2_2018_ITD_Total_Paid,
CAST(TRIM(Q2_2018_ITD_Deductible_PaidLoss) + 
TRIM(Q2_2018_ITD_Deductible_PaidALAE) AS decimal(20,2)) AS 
Q2_2018_ITD_Total_Deductible_Paid,
CAST(TRIM(Q2_2018_ITD_PaidLoss) - TRIM(Q2_2018_ITD_Deductible_PaidLoss) AS 
decimal(20,2)) AS Q2_2018_ITD_Net_PaidLoss,
CAST(TRIM(Q2_2018_ITD_PaidALAE) - TRIM(Q4_2017_ITD_PaidLoss) AS 
decimal(20,2)) AS Q2_2018_ITD_Net_PaidALAE,
CAST(TRIM(Q4_2017_ITD_Deductible_PaidLoss) + 
TRIM(Q4_2017_ITD_Deductible_PaidALAE) AS decimal(20,2)) AS 
Q4_2017_ITD_Total_Deductible_Paid
FROM table.Paids_1;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS table.Paids_3;
CREATE TABLE table.Paids_3 AS SELECT ID_Source, TPA_Claim_Number, File, ADJ, 
Policy_Number, Claimant, Insured, Report_Date, Accident_Date, Company, 
BusinessDivision, Subdivision, SectionName, GreatPlainsCode, Premium_State, 
ASL, Accident_Year, DAC, Claims_IND, Hurricane, 
Hurricane_Catastrophe_Description, CAT,Total_Recovery, LOB, Risk_Country, 
Clmnt, Effective_Date, Effective_Year, Expiration_Date, Sub_Policy_Number, 
Policy_Type, Policy_Symbol, WINS_Claim_Number, Claim_Description, 
Q2_2018_ITD_PaidLoss, Q2_2018_ITD_PaidALAE, Q2_2018_ITD_Deductible_PaidLoss, 
Q2_2018_ITD_Deductible_PaidALAE, Q4_2017_ITD_PaidLoss, Q4_2017_ITD_PaidALAE, 
Q4_2017_ITD_Deductible_PaidLoss, Q4_2017_ITD_Deductible_PaidALAE, 
Q2_2018_ITD_Total_Paid, Q2_2018_ITD_Total_Deductible_Paid, 
Q2_2018_ITD_Net_PaidLoss, Q2_2018_ITD_Net_PaidALAE, 
Q4_2017_ITD_Total_Deductible_Paid,
CAST(TRIM(Q2_2018_ITD_Net_PaidLoss) + TRIM(Q2_2018_ITD_Net_PaidALAE) AS 
decimal(20,2)) AS Q2_2018_ITD_Total_Net_Paid,
CAST(TRIM(Q2_2018_ITD_Net_PaidLoss) + TRIM(Q2_2018_ITD_Net_PaidALAE) AS 
decimal(20,2)) AS Q4_2017_ITD_Total_Paid,
CAST(TRIM(Q4_2017_ITD_PaidLoss) - TRIM(Q4_2017_ITD_Deductible_PaidLoss) AS 
decimal(20,2)) AS Q4_2017_ITD_Net_PaidLoss,
CAST(TRIM(Q4_2017_ITD_PaidALAE) - TRIM(Q4_2017_ITD_Deductible_PaidALAE) AS 
decimal(20,2)) AS Q4_2017_ITD_Net_PaidALAE,
CAST(TRIM(Q2_2018_ITD_PaidLoss) - TRIM(Q4_2017_ITD_PaidLoss) AS 
decimal(20,2)) AS Q2_2018_YTD_PaidLoss,
CAST(TRIM(Q2_2018_ITD_PaidALAE) - TRIM(Q4_2017_ITD_PaidALAE) AS 
 decimal(20,2)) AS Q2_2018_YTD_Paid_ALAE,
CAST(TRIM(Q2_2018_ITD_Deductible_PaidLoss) - 
TRIM(Q4_2017_ITD_Deductible_PaidLoss) AS decimal(20,2)) AS 
Q2_2018_YTD_Deductible_PaidLoss,
CAST(TRIM(Q2_2018_ITD_Deductible_PaidALAE) - 
TRIM(Q4_2017_ITD_Deductible_PaidALAE) AS decimal(20,2)) AS 
Q2_2018_YTD_Deductible_PaidALAE
FROM table.Paids_2;
```

Per the above example, I had to create table 2 to define the field Q4_2017_ITD_Deductible_PaidALAE because the 2 fields used when calculating it "
"Q2_2018_ITD_Deductible_PaidALAE" and "Q4_2017_ITD_Deductible_PaidALAE" are calculated in table 1.

```
CAST(TRIM(Q2_2018_ITD_Deductible_PaidALAE) - 
TRIM(Q4_2017_ITD_Deductible_PaidALAE) AS decimal(20,2)) AS 
Q2_2018_YTD_Deductible_PaidALAE
```

Right now to generate all the fields that I want, I'm creating 6 tables and then also selecting all the static fields in the first part of the select each time I create a new table. I'm pretty new to SQL so I'm sure there's a much easier way to do this.

Thanks!

Comment: Calculated columns? i think you mean generated columns?  Besides generated columns in MySQL looks this way ..  `column_name data_type AS (SQL_expression/calcuation)` see documentation https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table-generated-columns.html

Comment: MySQL generated columns have different syntax. If you want it nested, you will have to repeat the calculation in code AFAIK